# Is there "build-dep" for debug symbols?

Tags: package-management, debugging

When we need to build package from source there is handy "build-dep" option that install everything needed for building package from source. Is there some built-in option to install "dbg" packages?

I know about "list-symbols-packages" script, but feel like this may be already implemented in newer package manager versions and I just can't find that option.